# Bayesian ratings in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have the following table in my db

```
  Name     |    total_stars   |      total_reviews
 Item A             27                       7
 Item B             36                       9
 Item C             27                       7
 Item D             30                       6
 Item E             0                        0
 Item F             0                        0
 Item F             15                       3
```

I was looking at [this article](http://www.andymoore.ca/2010/02/bayesian-ratings-your-salvation-for-user-generated-content/) and was trying to implement bayesian rankings in postgresql database.

The formula given for the rank is

```
br = ( (avg_num_votes * avg_rating) + (this_num_votes * this_rating) ) / 
(avg_num_votes + this_num_votes)
```

where:

- avg_num_votes: The average number of votes of all items that have num_votes>0
- avg_rating: The average rating of each item (again, of those that have num_votes>0)
- this_num_votes: number of votes for this item
- this_rating: the rating of this item

This is the query I came up with, but it is not working:

```
with avg_num_votes as (
      select AVG(total_reviews) 
           from business 
           where total_reviews != 0), 
       avg_rating as (
          select AVG(total_stars/total_reviews) 
          from business 
          where total_reviews != 0)
select * from business 
  order by ((avg_num_votes * avg_rating) + (total_stars)) / (avg_num_votes + total_reviews);
```

I am getting: `ERROR:  column "avg_num_votes" does not exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator `WITH` in Postgres is only used to create additional working queries to be used in main query.

This query is using sub-selects in FROM clause instead and works as you expect:

```
SELECT business.* FROM business,
     (SELECT avg(total_reviews) AS v
      FROM business 
      WHERE total_reviews != 0
     ) AS avg_num_votes,
     (SELECT avg(total_stars/total_reviews) AS v 
      FROM business 
      WHERE total_reviews != 0
     ) AS avg_rating
ORDER BY ((avg_num_votes.v * avg_rating.v) + (total_stars)) / (avg_num_votes.v + total_reviews)
```

---

**EDIT**: Actually, using `WITH` is also possible, but does not seem to be shorter compared to first form. Also, it is less portable - first solution will work on MySQL, but this will not:

```
WITH
    avg_num_votes AS (
        SELECT avg(total_reviews) AS v
        FROM business 
        WHERE total_reviews != 0
    ),
    avg_rating AS (
        SELECT avg(total_stars/total_reviews) AS v
        FROM business
        WHERE total_reviews != 0
    )
SELECT business.*
FROM business, avg_num_votes, avg_rating
ORDER BY ((avg_num_votes.v * avg_rating.v) + (total_stars)) / (avg_num_votes.v + total_reviews)
```

Comment: WITH is standard SQL, a common table expression and it can be recursive as well. It's supported by many databases that use SQL, but not implemented in MySQL. Like many other SQL constructions, MySQL is getting behind.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0141d/3)

```
with av as (
    select avg(total_reviews) avg_num_votes
    from business
    where total_reviews > 0
), ar as (
    select name, avg(total_stars * 1.0 / total_reviews) avg_rating
    from business
    where total_reviews > 0
    group by name
)
select b.*, avg_rating, avg_num_votes,
    (avg_num_votes * avg_rating + total_stars)
    /
    (avg_num_votes + total_reviews) br
from
    business b
    left join
    ar on ar.name = b.name
    inner join
    av on true
order by br, b.name
    ;
  name  | total_stars | total_reviews |     avg_rating     |   avg_num_votes    |                 br                 
--------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------
 Item A |          27 |             7 | 3.8571428571428571 | 6.4000000000000000 | 3.85714285714285712238805970149254
 Item C |          27 |             7 | 3.8571428571428571 | 6.4000000000000000 | 3.85714285714285712238805970149254
 Item B |          36 |             9 | 4.0000000000000000 | 6.4000000000000000 | 4.00000000000000000000000000000000
 Item D |          30 |             6 | 5.0000000000000000 | 6.4000000000000000 | 5.00000000000000000000000000000000
 Item F |           0 |             0 | 5.0000000000000000 | 6.4000000000000000 | 5.00000000000000000000000000000000
 Item F |          15 |             3 | 5.0000000000000000 | 6.4000000000000000 | 5.00000000000000000000000000000000
 Item E |           0 |             0 |                    | 6.4000000000000000 |
```

Comment: You could also use window function here for less verbosity:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0141d/15)

**Query 1**:

    select *,
           (avg_num_votes * avg_rating + total_stars) / (avg_num_votes + total_reviews) AS br
      from (select *,
                   avg(nullif(total_stars, 0) * 1.0 / nullif(total_reviews, 0)) over (partition by name) AS avg_rating,
                   avg(nullif(total_reviews, 0)) over () AS avg_num_votes
              from business) business
     order by br, name